# MySQL - How to get the sum of distinct rows of a hasMany associations in a query of two hasMany associations?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Background:**

I have three tables namely productions, production_lines and operations.

The production_lines has a reference to its previous production line with column named 'parent_id'. The depth of the production_lines should equal the operations.

Here are their relationships:

```
Production_lines has many (child) production_lines.
Production_lines belongs to Production.
Productions has many operations.
```

**Problem:**

I have to create a single selection query that uses the number of operations and the total quantity out for selection purposes. The problem is that the children production lines are duplicated because of the joining of the operations table. How can I get the sum of the quantity of the children production lines distinctively?

**Current Solution:**

```
SELECT 
    `ProductionLine`.`id`,
    `ProductionLine`.`operation_number`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `Production.StockCode.Operations`.id) AS 'numberOfOperations',
    # This is where the problem is: It sums up including the duplicated entries due to Operations table.
    SUM(ChildrenProductionLines.dozen_quantity * 12 + ChildrenProductionLines.piece_quantity) AS 'quantityOut'
FROM 
    `production_lines` AS `ProductionLine`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `productions` AS `Production` 
    ON `ProductionLine`.`production_id` = `Production`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `operations` AS `Production.Operations` 
    ON `Production.Operations`.`production_id` = `Production`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `production_lines` AS `ChildrenProductionLines` 
    ON `ProductionLine`.`id` = `ChildrenProductionLines`.`parent_id`
GROUP BY `ProductionLine`.`id`
HAVING `operation_number` < `numberOfOperations`
ORDER BY `id`;
```

Comment: Try moving the `OUTER JOIN`s into a `WHERE id IN ( subquery )`. Or into a `JOIN` with a `GROUP BY` and a `COUNT()` column...

Comment: At first test, I was surprised it worked. But unfortunately, if I tried two children production lines having the same dozen_quantity, piece_quantity, then it treats them as the same and produced inaccurate results.

Comment: Is subquery the only solution?

Comment: Is that a problem?

Comment: Not really. It's just that I have to write raw SQL instead of using the ORM API. Haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT `id`, `operation_number`, `numberOfOperations`,
       SUM( `dozen_quantity` * 12 + `piece_quantity`) AS `quantityOut`
FROM `production_lines`
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `P`.`id`, COUNT( `C`.`id`) AS  `numberOfOperations`
            FROM `productions` AS `P`
            LEFT JOIN `operations` AS `O` ON `O`.`production_id` = `P`.`id`
            LEFT JOIN `production_lines` AS `C` ON `P`.`id` = `C`.`parent_id`
            GROUP BY `P`.`id`
          ) AS `Q` ON `production_id` = `Q`.`id`
WHERE `operation_number` < `numberOfOperations`
ORDER BY `id`;
```

Comment: Looks like sub-query is really the solution if there are at least two hasMany associations. Thanks!